# Haskell: parse error on input '|'

Tags: haskell, guard, parse-error

I have the following code, designed to take a duple from `m` and replace the the duple that starts with `s` with the evaluation of expression `e`

```
exec (Assign s e) m = assign s (eval e m) m
where assign _ _ [] = error ("undef var " ++ s)
    assign s v (x:xs)
        | fst x == s = if sameKind v (fst x)
                        then (fst x,v):xs
                        else error "type error in assign"
        | otherwise = x:(assign s v xs)
            where sameKind (VInt a) (VInt b) = True
                sameKind (VBool a) (VBool b) = True
                sameKind _ _ = False
```

When compiling, I get the error: `parse error on input '|'`

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You appear to be indenting with tabs. Use spaces and it has a higher chance of working. (If you want to use tabs, you have to split things across more lines. Tabs are also bad for alignment.)

Comment: replaced tabs with spaces, now have parse error on input 'assign' on the third line. so I guess that would be a new question then.

Comment: All your `assign`s have to line up with each other, as do the `sameKind`s.

Comment: Your first `where` (under `exec`) should be indented more.

Comment: that one is indented, something must have happened during the copy and paste. Anyways I aligned it and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Haskell 98 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html):

> Tab stops are 8 characters apart.

Your code appears to be designed for 5 (?) space tabs; change your editor's tab settings or stop using tabs and the problem will go away.

The reason is: Haskell thinks you indented it like this:

```
where assign _ _ [] = error ("undef var " ++ s)
        assign s v (x:xs)
```

which, as you can see, means the start of the second definition is still inside the RHS of the first definition.

Also:

Don't do this:

```
where f [] = one_expr
      f (x:xn) = another_expr
```

since it can make it hard to pick the `where` keyword and the first equation apart from each other, and also since it means you depend on what Haskell thinks the relative width of the `where` keyword and your indentation is, which is what bit you this time.  Tabs are fine in Haskell as long as you only depend on the leading indentation on a given line and are consistent, but that means you *always* need to have a line break (and further indent) after `where`, `let`, `case`/`of`, `do`, and possibly others I'm forgetting.  (Except `do` and `let` when the whole construct is on one line, of course).